# AUTO SUM textboxt with value in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sum

I need your help.

I have two textbox with random numbers and 1 textbox to show the total.

The total textbox will run a `sum` function if I click or fill the Qty1 or Qty2 textbox.

I would like to change it to: if I reload the page, the `Total` textbox will auto sum the Qty1 and Qty2 textbox and show the value.

```js
function findTotal(){
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
 }
```

```html
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" value="<?php $digits = 3; echo rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);?>"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" value="<?php $digits = 3; echo rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);?>"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```

Thanks before . . .

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post the actual code, ideally in a runnable snippet in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering the function on the `onblur` event so it will only trigger once you focus out the `input` element.
You should call the function on page load, check the snippet.

You can also achieve it with a `keyup` event once after the page is loaded:

```js
function findTotal(){
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
 };
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       findTotal();
    });
```

```html
Qty1 : <input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" value="2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" value="3"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using jQuery as well, it would look a lot more elegant :)

```js
var qty1 = $('input[name="qty1"]');
var qty2 = $('input[name="qty2"]');
var total = $('input[name="total"]');

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(qty1).val(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
 $(qty2).val(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
  
 $(total).val(Number($(qty1).val()) + Number($(qty2).val()));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
      <form id="calcForm" class="border p-4">
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="qty1">Quantity 1</label>
          <input name="qty1" type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="qty2">Quantity 2</label>
          <input name="qty2" type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        
        <hr class="py-4">
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="total">Total</label>
          <input name="total" type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    };
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       findTotal();
    });
```

```html
Qty1 : <input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" value="2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" value="3"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```